# Google Maps Walking Directions replace Exact Coordinates with nearest road. Is there a workaround?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, w3c-geolocation

Long story short, I have a HTML5 GeoPositioning enabled map on a phone. I have the current location, I want to show directions to specific coordinates.

Google maps is replacing the exact coordinates with the nearest road.

This is not close enough for my needs. Is there any way to force google maps directions to go to the exact spot, even if there's no road there?

[image: Image showing offset]

Comment: Why can't you just add a polyline between the end of the directions and the desired marker?

Comment: Thought of this afterwards, it's kind of a kludge though. Almost done implementing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I welcome any better answers.

What I did, is make a dotted polyline between the end of the last direction, and the actual point I'm going to, much the same as geocodezip described.

[image]

Comment: I think that's the best you can expect. Google's database knows about major highways and many major pedestrian ways but not every little footpath and alleyway in every city.